# How to get autocomplete edittext as a SearchBar in android?

Tags: java, android, material-design, searchbar

I've made a basic browser, and I want to use autocomplete edittext in my ActionBar(ToolBar).

I have read this--> https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style
It says that I need an adapter that provides the keywords list for auto-completion, but I need it for prediction purposes. Using a text resource for prediction will make it static(limited).

I need it as our mobile browsers have, just type a keyword and it suggests you. It suggests you a word or a complete sentence.

like this screenshot:

[image]

please help me... Thank You :-)

Answer (score 1):

use 'AutoCompleteTextView' instead of normal EditText.

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```